# what does ' mean in powershell script while working with azure?

Tags: shell, powershell, azure

Below is the code -

```
return Publish-Infrastructure `
            -settingsFileName $settingsFileName `
            -armDeploymentTemplateFile $armDeploymentTemplateFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about the back quote (`)? If so, it simply means that you are letting the current statement continue to the next line. All statements following the back quote until the last valid code line without back quote will be executed as a single command in powershell.
Hope this answers your query.

Answer (score 1):

(`) is  a line continuation in PowerShell. If you see [Help about_Escape_character](https://www.sapien.com/powershell/abouthelp/escape_characters/) in your PowerShell console, you will see the below info.

```
USING LINE CONTINUATION

   The escape character tells Windows PowerShell that the command continues
   on the next line.

   For example:

     PS C:\> Get-Process `
     >> PowerShell

     Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
     -------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
         340       8    34556      31864   149     0.98   2036 PowerShell
```